# Explaining "dx" and "dy" as ball properties

Tags: 2d

A ball in a 2D volleyball game is described by 4 variables, `x` , `y`, `dx` and `dy`. What exactly does it mean by `dx` and `dy`?

Comment: Without providing more detail, it would just be a guess.  They are variables.  We do not know the variable type, nor do we know how they are used.  You only provide the variable name.

Comment: I have unfortunately only these informations as in my post.

Comment: My guess is that they are the delta position, or the previous position, of the ball.

Comment: I've seen this before, in computer graphics. Hopefully my diagrams provide more insight.

Comment: Typically, it means Delta. Or distance/difference moved.

Comment: Did you sleep through the lecture? Ask your TA.

Comment: reverting changes. While this question can be *mistaken* to be about movement, it actually as no bearing or mention of movement, whatsoever. At best, this is about *scale*. If this confuses you, @DamhanPavlica, please refer to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered this, before, when dealing with computer graphics. In these cases, `x` and `y` are the co-ordinates for the *center* of the circle, while `dx` and `dy` are the *dimensions* (or commonly, the *diameter*) of the circle.

[image: Diagram of a circle, displaying midpoint (x,y) and dimensions (DX by DY).]

---

This seems especially valid in the described scenario, even if the volleyball would typically be a perfect circle (i.e. we only need a single diameter, as `dx == dy`). This is not always the case, in animation. A common practice for basic shapes is to simply alter the *width* or *height* with movement, to show greater animation.

[image: A standard textbook diagram displaying the common dimension changes in an animated ball.]

Answer (score 5):

I guess it is the **speed** of the ball.

At each frame, you can update the coordinates of the ball by doing

```
x = x + dx;
y = y + dy;
```

You should not update the position as written above in real life. If you are doing this in a game loop you should always keep track of the "delta", the time between 2 frames. That way, even if users have a different FPS, the ball will still move the same.

The code will look like :

```
x = x + dx * delta;
y = y + dy * delta;
```

The more time between 2 frames, the more distance traveled by the ball.

Comment: Please note that if you want to check previous versions or changes to a post (including your own), you can click on the "edited x min ago" link. This is a better alternative then adding the "edit:" ammendments that are more commonly associated with forums. +1 for adding the info on why you *would not* just use position and speed; I see people miss that one a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The dx and dy naming convention comes from calculus. In calculus you often find the derivative of a function which is often read as "the change in x" or "the change in y". These terms are notated using dx, dy, dz, etc. You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz%27s_notation).